# Installing on a remote machine without being root

Tags: installation, tmux, root

I mostly work on a linux remote machine for which I have an account but I am not the root user. I have never really understood what that means for my ability to install things.

I know that I can `pip install` things on my "part of the system" if I add `--user`. I also see that I can install things in my conda environment.

I would like to install `tmux`. I see that I can do this by doing `sudo apt-get install tmux` but obviously I can't `sudo` as I am not the root user. Is it possible for me to install it some other way or can only the system admin do this? If it is the latter, why can I install some things but not others?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pip is for Python libraries and whatnot and it supports installing them without root in your home directory. apt-get is for the Linux distribution's binary packages, it does not support this and in general you cannot install the binary packages without root.

By far the easiest solution is to ask your sysadmin or someone who has root to install tmux, it will be easy for them to do.

If you can't do this and the box has a compiler installed you could build tmux from source, this is kind of a big question if you aren't already familiar with building C software on Linux and may be more or less involved depending which dependencies are already installed and which you also need to build from source.

To build tmux 3.0a you need: a C compiler, make, yacc or bison, libevent, ncurses.

If you have another Linux box of a similar era to the one you are using remotely and on which you do have root, a good option is to build a static tmux and copy the tmux binary to the remote host where you don't have root - that way you can install all the dependencies needed to build with your package manager and don't need to build them. For example to do this on a Debian box you would do:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential bison ncurses-dev libevent-dev
wget https://github.com/tmux/tmux/releases/download/3.0a/tmux-3.0a.tar.gz
tar -zxf tmux-3.0a.tar.gz
cd tmux-3.0a
./configure --prefix=$HOME/local --enable-static
make
scp tmux myuser@myhost:~
```

If you can't do this, and your remote Linux box has a compiler (check with `gcc -v`) and yacc (try `yacc -V`) then you can first build ncurses and libevent, here is an article that shows you how to do that for a slightly older tmux version - there are a number of other articles as well if you search: https://jdhao.github.io/2018/10/16/tmux_build_without_root_priviledge/ The one this this article doesn't mention is that you will also need to do `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/local/lib` as well as `PATH` to run tmux, you can put both exports in your shell startup files (.profile or .bashrc or whatever).

A good start is to download and untar the tmux tarball and run `./configure --prefix=$HOME/local` and see what happens - if it fails it should give you a clue what else you need to build, if it succeeds you can run `make && make install` then run tmux from `$HOME/local/bin/tmux`.

Answer (score 0):

There is now an AppImage distributed  as well which can be used without root access.
https://github.com/tmux/tmux/releases